# Oracle client not able to connect using DBI::ORACLE

Tags: oracle, perl

Oracle client not able to connect .
Error: 
Database connect failed:(UNKNOWN OCI STATUS 1804) OCIInitialize. Check ORACLE_HOME and NLS

Answer (score 0):

This error is nearly always that ORACLE_HOME is not set properly and sometimes missing/incorrect NLS environment variables.

you should have smth like this where you set all pathes

```
#!/u00/app/xxx/bin/perl 
my $ORACLE_HOME = "/u00/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.2"; 
my $ORACLE_SID="xxxxT11";
$ENV{ORACLE_HOME}=$ORACLE_HOME;
$ENV{ORACLE_SID}=$ORACLE_SID;
$ENV{PATH}="$ORACLE_HOME/bin";
$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}="$ORACLE_HOME/lib";
use strict;
use DBI;
my $dbh = DBI->connect( 'dbi:Oracle:orcl', 'scott', 'tiger', ) || die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";
$dbh->disconnect;
```